# How to display all data from database in java swing

Tags: java, database, swing

I'm working with Java swing. I have a database for some employees and I have to show all the information for one employee on labels (and all labels in a panel).

Because I'm new in Java swing, I don't know how to display the information just for one row in the labels. And in the end, how can I repeat this panel for all the others employees?

Comment: you can create a loop over the `ResultSet` of a query

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a Select on a database in java you should assign the result of that select to a ResultSet. After that you can view the data using a for loop. In your case, if you only want to get the first employee then use a variable that counts the number of employees and add it to your for loop condition.